# Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin Dotfuscator CE Config File Creation Problem

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, dotfuscator

I have followed the instructions at https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html#setup-targets and verified the accuracy multiple times. It says the first build will create DotfuscatorConfig.xml but it fails with Error 1. Then it says to set verbosity to Normal, so I did, but still no revelation why it won't create the file. I can change the build back to Debug and it builds fine, but changing back to release produces the same two errors. Has anyone experienced this and solved it?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

Error       The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscator.exe" /p:InDir="obj\Release\100\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\Release\100\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\Release" "obj\Release\100\DotfuscatorXamarin\Template.dfconfig" /in:+"${configdir}${InDir}\WetYourWhistle.Android.dll",+"${configdir}${InDir}\WetYourWhistle.dll" /makeconfig:"DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" exited with code 1.   WetYourWhistle.Android  C:\Users\leuol\source\repos\WetYourWhistle\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets    508
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "_DotfuscatorXamarin_SetProjectPropsTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\leuol\source\repos\WetYourWhistle\WetYourWhistle\WetYourWhistle.Android\DotfuscatorConfig.xml'.
File name: 'C:\Users\leuol\source\repos\WetYourWhistle\WetYourWhistle\WetYourWhistle.Android\DotfuscatorConfig.xml'
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri)
at InlineCode._DotfuscatorXamarin_SetProjectPropsTask.Execute() in c:\Users\leuol\AppData\Local\Temp\r0wqtkdr\r0wqtkdr.0.cs:line 93
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() WetYourWhistle.Android  C:\Users\leuol\source\repos\WetYourWhistle\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets    520
Error       The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscator.exe" /p:InDir="obj\Release\100\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\Release\100\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\Release" "obj\Release\100\DotfuscatorXamarin\Template.dfconfig" /in:+"${configdir}${InDir}\WetYourWhistle.Android.dll",+"${configdir}${InDir}\WetYourWhistle.dll" /makeconfig:"DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" exited with code 1.   WetYourWhistle.Android  C:\Users\leuol\source\repos\WetYourWhistle\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets    508

UPDATE - Now the code is compiling without error but still will not produce the DotfuscatorConfig.xml file. Not sure what else to try and it appears that nobody else knows either.

Comment: As indicated elsewhere, PreEmptive will not support the CE version of their software even though they require registration and licensing. Hoping the answer has been found, though, by using the DotfuscatorUI (Tools-PreEmptive Dotfuscator Community). Load the dll file which was built by Visual Studio and click Build. It generates a Dotfuscated directory with the obfuscated dll and Map.xml file.
It is expected that these two files can now be placed into the bin-Release directory and used to build the Android app with obfuscation.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to temporary change the command dotfuscator.exe to dotfuscatorUI.exe :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileName>DotfuscatorConfig.xml</DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileNam
    <DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorUI.exe</DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>
    <DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>true</DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>
    <DotfuscatorEnabled>true</DotfuscatorEnabled>
    <DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">true</DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="../../PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin/PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets" />
```

Then start build. The dotfuscator UI starts with a window:
[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb2OR.png)

Then press "Build". After it finishes, close then window by clicking "x" on top right. Then the output on Visual Studio shows a successful result:

```
Build started: Project: [AppName].Android, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
    [AppName].Android -> D:\Users\[UserName]\source\repos\[FolderName]\[AppName]\[AppName].Android\bin\Release\[AppName].Android.dll
    Running Dotfuscator with a new config file based on project references...
    Finished running Dotfuscator with a new config file.
D:\Users\[UserName]\source\repos\[FolderName]\[AppName]\[AppName].Android\[AppName].Android.csproj : warning : A new Dotfuscator config file was generated because it did not exist: 'DotfuscatorConfig.xml'.
```

You can see dotfuscatorconfig.xml is created at a folder [AppName].Android.

Then revert back from dotfuscatorUI.exe to dotfuscator.exe .

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileName>DotfuscatorConfig.xml</DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileNam
    <DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscator.exe</DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>
    <DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>true</DotfuscatorGenerateConfigFileIfMissing>
    <DotfuscatorEnabled>true</DotfuscatorEnabled>
    <DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">true</DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="../../PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin/PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets" />
```

Then the build should work without a UI popup.